# Eventos jQuery executa automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    $(function(){
      function teste(teste){
        console.log(teste);
      }
      $('element').on('click', teste('teste'));
    })
```

Quando executo esse código a função `teste` é disparada sem eu clicar no botão ou seja, automaticamente.

E no seguinte código, funciona tudo ok.

```
    $(function(){
      function teste(){
        console.log('teste');
      }
      $('element').on('click', teste);
    })
```

Por que o primeiro código não funciona?

Comment: Qual é o seu objetivo aqui? O que você está tentando fazer?

Answer (score 7):

Ao declarar uma função, é criada uma referência a ela com o respectivo nome.

Veja o seguinte exemplo, um pouco modificado para "desconfundir" os nomes:

```js
function teste(param){
    console.log(param);
}
console.log(teste);
```

Note que `teste` é uma referência à função declarada. Porém, no momento em que você usa o parêntesis à direita da referência, você está diretamente solicitando a execução da função:

```js
teste('teste') //executa a função
```

Se a sua intenção é passar uma referência e os parâmetros ao mesmo tempo, isso não é possível. Pelo menos não dessa forma.

Uma possibilidade para passar parâmetros arbitrários para uma função usada no `on()` do jQuery pode ser encontrada no parâmetro `data`, conforme a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
    function teste(param) {
        console.log(param.data.teste);
    }
    $('elemento').on('click', {teste: 'teste'}, teste);
});
```

Passando um objeto com a propriedade `teste` no segundo argumento da função `on` do jQuery, podemos acessar seu valor quando a função `teste` for executada através do atributo `data` do parâmetro recebido.

### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/sd4r8/)